# Best way to check if file exist and it is readable in java

Tags: java, file, java-io

Could you please let me know what is the best way to check if file exist and readable in java? I think of following two ways. But, I am not able to think of which one is better.

**Option#1-**

```
String filePath = "file_location"
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath)) {
    fis.read();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // File does not exist.
} catch (IOException e) {
    // File is not readable.
}
```

**Option#2-**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;

File file = new File("file_location");
if (!Files.isRegularFile(file.toPath())) {
    // File does not exist or it is not a file.
}

if (Files.isReadable(file.toPath())) {
    // File is not readable.
}
```

Comment: Your first option checks the action you actually carry out, while your second first performs some checks and very slightly later does something, which opens a window for a race condition. This happens more often in reality, e.g. when two daily jobs run at the same time. But really, this is mostly a matter of opinion and I'll vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

I would move to `java.nio` **entirely**, which means getting rid of `java.io` at all and then choose a slightly adjusted version of your second option:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path file = Paths.get("L:\\ocation\\of\\the\\file");
    if (!Files.exists(file)) {
        // File does not exist
    } else if (!Files.isRegularFile(file)) {
        // File is not a file, maybe a directory
    } else if (!Files.isReadable(file)) {
        // File is not readable.
    } else {
        // everything is right, process the file
    }
}
```

This question may be somehow opinion-based, but I think it is not primarily due to the comparison of old and modern packages.

Comment: [`isRegularFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isRegularFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-) *"[follows] symbolic links [...] and the file attribute of the final target of the link is read".*

Comment: This is the correct answer.  java.io.File is old and should be avoided unless its use is absolutely necessary (such as when working with other APIs that require int).

Comment: @Andreas thanks, I removed the related words from the code comment

Comment: Don't nest `if` statements if avoidable, i.e. revert the condition of the outer `if` statement, like already done for the first inner `if` statement. Then change `if` to `else if` on the subsequent `if` statements, because there is no guarantee that the `if` blocks won't complete normally. In short, code should be `if (! exists) { ... } else if (! isRegularFile) { ... } else if (! isReadable) { ... } else { ... use file here ... }`

Comment: @Andreas yeas, thanks again. I will update this later, for now, it is just a quick answer...